# Margin Trade: How do I calculate my margin level based on leverage and price?

Tags: trading, margin

Hoping someone could help a noob. Let's say I have 10,000 USD in an account and want to short ETH with 1,000 USD with 5x leverage (5k USD total).

With this, my margin level be 1,000%, yes? (10,000 / 1,000)x100

If the price of ETH were then to go down 20% after opening this position, what would my margin level be?

Answer (score 1):

Before the price change, you have:

1. +$10,000 cash deposited
2. +$5,000 from sale of eth borrowed
3. -$5,000 worth of ETH owed

So equity is $10,000, margin used is $5,000/5.

After the price change, you have:

1. +$10,000 cash deposited
2. +$5,000 from sale of eth borrowed
3. -$4,000 worth of ETH owed

Now, equity is $11,000, margin used is $4,000/5 or $800. That gives a margin level of 1375%.

Comment: Thanks, David! So if ETH were to go UP 20%, it'd be the following:  

+$10,000 cash deposited  
+$5,000 from sale of eth borrowed
-$6,000 worth of ETH owed

Equity is now 9,000. Margin used = 6000/5 or $1200

(9,000 / 1200) x100 = 750% as margin level?

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's correct.